# Regular Expression,Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, expression

I need to validade a string in the following format:

numbers, letters and _ 
Minimum length 4 and max length 15
At least 1 letter [a-z]

For example:

Valid:

- ABCD
- ABCDE
- ABC_
- 01A_
- A12345_BCDW1234

Not Valid:

- ABC
- 01A
- A12345_BCDW123411
- _1212392034
- _
- A_1

I made a couple tries but none work.

Comment: Please make your title more specific and give us some examples.

Comment: `I made a couple tries but none work.` isn't going to work here. Show your tries so we can teach you where you got wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in just one regex, the validation of constraints on length {4,15} and "must contains a letter" must be done independently.

```
$test_inputs = array(
      'ABCD', 'ABCDE', 'ABC_', '01A_', 'A12345_BCDW1234'
    , 'ABC', '01A', 'A12345_BCDW123411', '_1212392034', '_', 'A_1'
);

$res = array();
foreach($test_inputs as $input)
{
    $res[$input] = (preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9_]{4,15}$/i', $input) && preg_match('/[A-Z]/i', $input));
}

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: "I don't think you can do this in just one regex"
That was really my problem... 
Thank you.